# Create multiple rows when joining with a table with multiple row values

Tags: mysql

I have three tables as shown below

```
Table A
Id
1
2
3
4
5

Table B
Id Value1
1  x
1  z
1  y
2  q
2  r
3  t

Table C
Id Value2
1  p
1  u
2  i
```

Left join just gets me one matching value from Table B and Table C based on the ID. I need the query to create multiple records while accommodating 'Null' where there is no data.

How do I join these tables and get the below output

```
Id Value1 Value2
1  x      p
1  z      u
1  y      Null
2  q      i
2  r      Null
3  t      Null
4  Null   Null
5  Null   Null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `LEFT JOIN` twice:

```
SELECT ta.id, tb.value1, tc.value2
FROM tableA ta
LEFT JOIN tableB tB ON tb.id = ta.id
LEFT JOIN tableC tc ON tc.id = ta.id
```